# Git asking for password from command line

Tags: git, gitosis

I setup git and gitosis on a server to manage my repos.  It's working properly for the initial shell account I set it up with, i.e. I can run:

```
git clone git@MYSERVER:gitosis-admin.git
```

But when I try to use the separate accounts I've created (via gitosis.conf) it keeps asking for a password:

```
git clone johndoe@MYSERVER:gitosis-admin.git
```

I setup the SSH key and pushed a copy to the keydir on the server.  This question seems to address the same problem, but the solution given is for tortoisegit.

[Git keeps asking for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162912/git-keeps-asking-for-password)

How do I tell git to use the ssh key instead of asking for a password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use your user name, you always say:

```
git clone git@MYSERVER:<repository>
```

Gitosis associates your name in its config file with the name of your key on the server. That is, you have lines like

```
[group users]
members = johndoe janeroe
writable = repo1 repo2
```

in gitosis.conf, and files johndoe.pub, janedoe.pub in gitosis-admin/keydir; gitosis will use the appropriate key for the user but you always use "git" as the user in the URL. That's because it's always using the "git" account.

Comment: I have a similar situation. Please read my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882545/gitosis-asking-for-password

Answer (score 2):

Well, I just read about gitosis, and AFAICT you should never ever be cloning from `johndoe@MYSERVER` when using it.  Always clone from `git@`, and make sure your ssh keys are set up correctly so that the server can use those to differentiate (for example) johndoe from janedoe.

What you do on the client side is add johndoe's SSH key to your keychain, remove any others the server will accept, and set your git user and email settings to id you as johndoe.  The server will compare the two, see that they match, and let you commit.  If you configure SSH to use someone else's key and then try to commit as johndoe with git, you may be able to connect to the server, but it will not let you proceed with a commit.

OTOH, because gitosis does not create actual user accounts, you can't ssh as johndoe into the machine, which also means you can't use johndoe@... addresses for the repository in git.  If you need to do that, you'll have to set your git server up another way.