# gitosis asking for password

Tags: git, passwords, ssh, rsa, gitosis

I have setup a gitosis server following instructions from [here](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way). It works fine for the initial user but I have recently added a new user. Here are the steps I took.

- Created an rsa keypair using `ssh-keygen` with filename johndoe.
- Then copied it to the keydir in gitosis admin repo.
- Edited the gitosis config file and added user johndoe to the list of members
- Commited the changes using `git commit -a -m "what i did"`
- Pushed the changes to the server

After that I tried to check out with the new keyfile. It asks for the passphrase and when I enter it correctly, it the asks for the password for user git!!!
There is not password for user git.

Now I have turned off PasswordAuthentication in sshd_config and now it says 'Permission denied (publickey). I have checked the git user's authorized_keys file and only one key is authorized inside it, i.e. the initial key for the gitosis admin.

I have also double checked the permissions on the ./gitosis-admin.git/hooks/post-update hook and it has 755

Comment: I don't even remember what I did to solve this or if I even did solve it. I currently use gitolite and feel it's much better. What should be done to a question like this?

Answer (score 6):

Gitosis is kind of stupid — is the filename you used for the keyfile literally "johndoe"? If so, change that:

```
git mv keydir/johndoe keydir/johndoe.pub
git commit -m "changed key name"
git push
```

and try again.

Also, as Arlen Cuss points out, make sure it actually *is* the public key, not the private key.

Comment: OP, if the issue is the public vs. private key, please accept Arlen Cuss's answer. I'm leaving this here for those people who've left the ".pub" off of public keys.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what gitosis *does* do if a private key is put in instead, but I assume it won't function, and that this may be the issue .. who knows :-}

Comment: @Arlen Cuss, it will install the private key in the authorized keys file, and then ssh won't work. (I've had people do it. :-) )

Answer (score 5):

Hi, I had the same problem, and I finally found a way out.

I had to follow the instructions given by many websites, but each time after

```
git clone git@[serveur_name]:gitosis-admin.git
```

It was asking password for GIT.

Resolution:
I have inserted the admin public key (the one created on my client user; then imported into the server's tmp directory) inside my `authorized_keys` file (located in the `/home/git/.ssh/` directory of the server) and it works now.

```
 cp authorized_keys authorized_keys.bak
 cat /tmp/id_dsa_git.pub >> authorized_keys
```

I found this @ http://fclose.com/b/linux/366/set-up-git-server-through-ssh-connection/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're putting your **public key** inside your gitosis repo, and not your private one!

When you generate a keyfile, you'll get a `.pub` file—use that one, but put the name in your `gitosis.conf` without the `.pub`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have also added (git add) the .pub-files, and committed and pushed them properly to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue with a private repository for work. I came across this answer and read the answers; [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8240747/63609) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4882891/63609) did the trick.

To sum it up for posterity, make sure you add the **`.pub`** key to the `gitosis-admin/keydir` directory. It has to be a **.pub** file.

Commit & Push your changes to **gitosis-admin**.

Your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` will be automatically updated so no need to cat-redirect the output of your public key file to it.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

one thing that often goes wrong for windows users and isn't catched by most of the tutorials out there (since they assume you're on a linux client)

msysgit, the windows git console, is looking for your **private key at /home/YOURUSERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa**
which at windows is (Windows 7) C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME.ssh\id_rsa

while most get it right with the folder, since its created automaticly, they miss that the file **HAS TO be named "id_rsa"** or it wont be used by msysgit. 
I didn't find a way to tell msysgit to use other keys

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what happened is that the post-update hook didn't run properly.

Check that ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys has your public key in it.

If not, the post-update hook didn't run. Permissions which have subsequently been changed? Some other configuration error. Copied from somewhere else?

1. On the server, checkout gitosis admin: git clone /path/to/gitosis-admin.git. Make an insignificant change to gitosis.conf. Check that your public key is  in keydir. I had to run this as the git user.
2. Commit gitosis.conf. git add gitosis.conf && git commit -m "refresh keys".
3. Now check authorized_keys file.
4. Change gitosis.conf back and commit again.

Test access. If authorized_keys isn't updated after this process, look in logs for error messages.