# Cannot clone git repo from ubuntu server with TortoiseGit

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu-10.04, tortoisegit, gitolite

I'm facing some problems while `git clone` a repo from my ubuntu server running **gitolite**.

First, I got a public key from the developer who wants to clone the repository from the server. It was a rsa key created with **putty**. So I did the following to parse it from the putty-style to openssh format with:

`ssh-keygen -i -f /tmp/ssh2/YourName.pub > /tmp/openssh/YourName.pub` (taken from http://gitolite.googlecode.com/git/doc/ssh-troubleshooting.mkd?r=d3a663d03f1027f909732d55d0519bdd84edb62c)

and uploaded the public key along with a new entry for the repo and the new user in the config file to gitolite-admin repo.

So far, so good.

The developer is using **** along with **putty** to connect to the server, which is running **git** on a *non-standard* port and he keeps on getting the same error over and over again:

```
Cloning into 'D:\path\to\dirctory'...
error: Recv failure: Connection was reset while accessing http://sub.domain.com/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)
```

Could anyone give me some advice about this issue?

---

EDIT:

In the meantime, we managed to `git clone` the repository by addressing it with the `ssh://` protocol instead of `git://`, so it doesn't seem like it is a problem of the rsa_public.key or something like that.

The iptables on the server are accepting connections through the port for git, but it keeps on giving the above mentioned error.

Comment: Could the developer choose OpenSSH when installing msysgit/putty? (as in http://codeslinging.blogspot.fr/2010/01/setting-up-tortoisegit-to-work-with-ssh.html), and generate its keys the usual way (as illustrated in http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/HowToSetUpGit.ashx). So the rever se http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224972/how-to-install-setup-tortoisegit-to-work-with-github .

Comment: hey,
as far as I know, the developer had putty installed before, installed **msysgit** and **tortoisegit** and created his keys with putty..

Comment: sure but when he installs msysgit and tortoiseGit, he has the choice between openssh (integrated with msysgit) and an external ssh layer (putty).

Comment: Also what exact address the user is using to clone his remote -- gitolite-managed-- repo? Not an http(s) one, I hope?

Comment: he has chosen the external ssh layer (putty) afaik. the address is not an http(s) one. he used git://git@remote.server.com:port/repo.git

Comment: Is there any firewall issue? Are you allowed to use the git port (9418)?

Comment: no, there shouldn't be a firewall issue as iptables is accepting traffic for the git port - the port is forwarded and appears to be another port when connecting from outside... now, the developer cloned the repo through ssh:// (and even connecting to the ssh-port!)

Comment: Ok: usually the git port is blocked somehow (http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.rtems.user/19350). If not on your side, maybe on the server side.

Comment: @VonC - I know it's a long time ago, but would you consider to change your last comment into an answer so I could mark this question as solved? thanks!

Comment: Sure. I have summarized the comments in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OP herom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073366/herom) initially commented that the developer used `git://git@remote.server.com:port/repo.git` as an address.

I asked if there was any firewall issue, preventing the use of the git port (**`9418`**), but the OP mentioned:

> no, there shouldn't be a firewall issue as iptables is accepting traffic for the git port - the port is forwarded and appears to be another port when connecting from outside...
>   Now, the developer cloned the repo through `ssh://` (and even connecting to the `ssh-port`!)

I note that the git port can sometime be blocked, as illustrated in [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.rtems.user/19350).
If not on the client side, maybe on the server side.