# Cannot pick an SSH client when installing TortoiseGIT

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I installed TortoiseGIT using TortoisePink as my SSH client. But I later found out that that was not the correct one to use for my purposes. So, I uninstalled TortoiseGIT and tried to re-install, but when I try to re-install it won't bring up the "Pick your ssh client" screen. I checked their website, but this issue is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/11249914/6309 help?

Comment: I was able to circumvent this problem by going to the TortoiseGIT settings page. Under "network" I noticed that the "TortoisePink.exe" file was still selected. So, I just changes this to "ssh.exe" without a path and viola! My issue is fixed. I will self answer this question as soon as I'm allowed.

Comment: Excellent. Pending that, +1 to your question, then :)

Comment: "Would stackoverflow.com/a/11249914/6309 help?" It does indeed! Thank you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

TortoiseGIT leaves key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseGit` in registry after uninstall.

I deleted it and was able to pick SSH client on next install.

Answer (score 18):

I was able to circumvent this problem by going to the TortoiseGIT settings page. Under "network" I noticed that the "TortoisePink.exe" file was still selected. So, I just changed this to "ssh.exe" without a path and viola! My issue is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I will add this here as I didn't want to reinstall TortoiseGit just for this and the other solutions did not help.

If you want to switch TortoiseGit to OpenSSH, simply run this at the command prompt:

```
tortoisegitproc /command:firststart
```