# git wpengine asking for password?

Tags: tortoisegit

I am using tortoisegit to try and pull down a production environment from wpengine.

I've just generated a public key and added it via wpengine's dashboard. I have generated a private key, and pointed tortoisegit to that file.

I then right click and select 'Git Clone' , and point the private key to my private key file. I then point it to the correct wpengine URL: git@git.wpengine.com:production/my_site.git.

Then it starts to connect and asks me for the git@git.wpengine.com password. Why does it keep asking me for that password, and not my private key passphrase?

[image]

Is my public key not linked to tortoisegit or something?

I've read up a bit and it seems this issue happens when you try and connect via https, but I have not intentionally done this. How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of this question: [Cannot pick an SSH client when installing TortoiseGIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653319/cannot-pick-an-ssh-client-when-installing-tortoisegit)

I was able to resolve the issue by right clicking, going down to 'TortoiseGit > Settings' then into 'Network' and changing the SSH client to 'ssh.exe' without any path.

I could then properly clone my repo.

Hope this helps someone in future. What a pain that was.