# Windows command line GIT password prompt

Tags: linux, windows, git, ssh, ssh-keys

I have mysysgit and TortoiseGit installed on a Windows PC, which connects to a remote Git repo on a Linux box. I have created ssh keys, and added them to the profile in TortoiseGit. When I interact with the remote repo in TortoiseGit, it all works fine. No password prompting. However, when I try to run Git commands from the command line, I get prompted for the SSH password.

What do I need to do so that I'm not prompted for the password from the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your git session references the `TortoisePLink.exe` (in GIT_SSH environment variable), as described in "[Why git can't remember my passphrase under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4356869/6309)":

(you might have done the first two steps already)

- convert your key for use with TortoiseGit's `pageant.exe` using TortoiseGit's `puttygen.exe`.
- Run TortoiseGit's `pageant.exe`, open your `.ppk` file ("Add Key"), and provide your passphrase for your key.
- add the environment variable:

  ```
  GIT_SSH=C:\full\path\to\TortoisePlink.exe
  ```

This assumes your [TortoiseGit is using `TortoisePlink.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11249914/6309).

---

The [OP scott80109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707301/scott80109) concludes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993630/windows-command-line-git-password-prompt/18997435#comment28131439_18997435):

> msysgit was installed to use Open SSH.
>   I changed it to use `plink`, and it now works without a prompt

---

[Erez A. Korn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609444/erez-a-korn) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993630/windows-command-line-git-password-prompt/18997435#comment48523240_18997435):

> I prefer to use openssh as it doesn't require me to have my key in an alternative format (ppk).
>   I've written a small wrapper to launch the `ssh-agent` and take care of business and then added it to my Windows Startup.
>   You can check the code in [**`erezak/ssh-agent-wrapper-win`**](https://github.com/erezak/ssh-agent-wrapper-win).

Comment: Thanks. Your post help me resolve it. msysgit was installed to use Open SSH. I changed it to use plink, and it now works without a prompt.

Comment: I prefer to use openssh as it doesn't require me to have my key in an alternative format (ppk). I've written a small wrapper to launch the ssh-agent and take care of business and then added it to my Windows Startup. You can check the code in  https://github.com/erezak/ssh-agent-wrapper-win

Comment: @ErezA.Korn Very nice! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use pageant. read this http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html and add you ssh-key to pageant. it affects globally.

Comment: Pageant is installed and the key has been added to it. I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @scott80109, do you have the `GIT_SSH` environment variable correctly pointing to PuTTY's `plink.exe`? Otherwise plain Git for Windows won't find it and will use its built-in SSH client (a bundled port of OpenSSH client). See the second screenshot [here](http://nathanj.github.io/gitguide/installing.html).

Answer (score 0):

My use case needed multiple github users with passphrase-protected ssh keys.

I sorted my `~.ssh/config` file to use different keys for different repo domains, as described [here](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996)

However, I don't want to type my passphrase every time, and I don't want to use ssh-agent.

Here's how I set up Pageant to ask for and remember my passphrase on Windows login:

- [Download the Putty Tools package](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)
- **Win+R** to open run dialog
- shell:startup to open the auto start folder in windows explorer
- Navigate to your Pageant folder in a separate Explorer window
- Right click and drag PAGEANT.EXE to the Startup folder. Choose **Create Shortcut**
- Right click the shortcut, properties, Shortcut tab
- Find the path to your .ppk encoded keypair

  - generate one with PUTTYGEN.EXE if you need a new one
  - convert one with PUTTYGEN.EXE  if you have a linux id_rsa file but no .ppk
  - win7+ : shift right click your key in Explorer, **Copy as path**
- Append the key path to the C:\whatever\PAGEANT.EXE line

  - e.g:  "Target: `C:\putty\PAGEANT.EXE plato_cambrian.ppk plato.ppk`"
  - If your keys aren't adjacent to PAGEANT you can use absolute paths or change "Start in:" which is Pageant's CWD
- Open the shortcut or reboot, and type your passphrases

Also, for anyone on ubuntu/linux mint who ended up here, I documented similar steps [here](http://group.cambrian.org/wiki/doku.php?id=github-ssh)