# TortoiseGit is still asking password despite having wincred as credential.helper and _netrc file

Tags: git, ssh, tortoisegit

I have read multiple answers explaining how to make TortoiseGit remember passwords. Unfortunately, after

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

and putting

```
machine IP
login ServerUserName
password Password
```

in `C:\Users\PCUserName\_netrc` TortoiseGit is *still* asking for my password (and so is `git fetch` from command line; I've selected "use TortoisePLink" when installing Git). I've also added user name and password manually in Credential Manager, which didn't help. I also have copied `.ssh` folder from my Linux workstation to `C:\Users\PCUserName` and have the key in `~/ServerUserName/authorized_keys` on the server. The protocol is `ssh:` and http/https isn't set up on server, so I can't try to switch to them.

Any ideas? I don't care about encrypting the password, since everything is on intranet.

Versions: msysgit 1.8.4-preview20130916, TortoiseGit 1.8.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

`_netrc` and `.ssh`? Those are for two different authentication mechanism.

The first one is for https (and don't need `wincred`), the second one for ssh.

Make sure wincred is not registered in your git config, and that HOME is defined in your user environment variable (then relaunch TortoiseGit).
It should pick up your `%HOME%\_netrc` credentials *if* your remote url is an https one.

Comment: "The protocol is ssh: and http/https isn't set up on server, so I can't try to switch to them." Ok, so I can't use _netrc.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov sure. Make sure your HOME is correctly set, and that your Pagent contains the passphrase of your private key (if you have a private key protected by a passphrase): http://stackoverflow.com/a/11249914/6309