# 'git push origin MyBranchName' throws error "HTTP Basic: Access denied"

Tags: git, gitlab

I am new to Git (just started 2 days ago). I'm attempting to create a project to practice the basic commands I've learned from [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-git).

**Where I am, so far:**

- **[success]** Create a new public git project (because I tried private and internal before but I could not clone it, and I don't know why). [Here it is](https://gitlab.com/portfolio-flame/speedtype).
- Added a `README.md` into the project.
- **[success]** Create a new branch named `develop`.
- **[success]** In my local folder `C:\gitprojects`, set global `user.name` and `user.email` with the commands:

  - `git config --global user.name <my user name>`
  - `git config --global user.email <my-email>`
- **[success]** Clone the project into my local folder `C:\gitprojects` with the command `git clone https://flamedenise19@gitlab.com/flamedenise19/speedtyping.git`
- **[success]** Create a local branch with the command `git checkout -b "develop"`.
- **[success]** Manually add a new file `test.txt` on local root folder for test pushing.
- **[success]** Commit the new file with the command `git commit -m "adds test.txt"`
- **[attempting]** Push the commit with the command `git push origin develop`

And now, I'm stuck with the `push` part. After entering `git push origin develop`, a new window pops up, asking for my credentials (see screenshot below):

[image]

So I did enter my credentials (the very same username and password I use when logging in to gitlab.com), but after that, I got this error (also see screenshot below):

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/flamedenise19/speedtyping.git/'
```

[image]

**QUESTIONS:**

- Why can't I push successfully, even with the correct username and password? Am I missing something or have I done something wrong along the way?
- Is there a way to remove the step of having to enter my credentials everytime I push something?

Please help.

> **NOTE:** I have seen **[THIS ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162912/git-keeps-asking-for-password)**, and the answers are mentioning Tortoise. Is it always required to use tortoise in order to
>   use Git?

**SOME BACKGROUND INFO:**

Two-Factor Authentication is **disabled** for my account (see screenshot below):

[image]

Comment: are u enter gitlab authentication ?

Comment: Also, if you didn't create a project from the dashboard, it would be rejected too.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi which dashboard are you referring to? I created the project in https://gitlab.com/projects/new itself (by clicking that " + " icon on the left of my profile image), and then cloned it in my local. Is this a wrong way to create a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are my ideas:

- Try if it works on the Git Bash
- Have you added a ssh key to your account? If yes remove it and try again. If not add one and try the ssh url.
- You don't necessarily need Tortoise Git but it may also work around your problem
- Try to re-install Git without the `Git Credential Manager for Windows`

When you've fixed the push problem you will also be able to clone it when it is private or internal.

Comment: I don't find any SSH key for my account anywhere in the settings. In the project itself however, there is SSH alongside the HTTP. I did not add it, it was just auto-generated when I created the project. Also, I don't see any option anywhere that would allow me to remove it.

Comment: I tried doing the push via Git Bash, but the error is still the same.

Comment: I also tried deleting everything from my local and cloned the project again using SSH (`git clone git@gitlab.com:flamedenise19/speedtyping.git`), but it gives me this error: `Permission denied (publickey).
Fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Comment: Wait... I stand corrected! There WAS an SSH key in my account. This could have been added when I was still with my former company (although I don't remember adding it myself since I didn't know how anyway). Nevertheless, I removed the SSH key, and then reinstalled Git - this time, unchecking the `Git Credential Manager for Windows`. And it did the trick! Your 1st and 3rd ideas worked for me. Than you.

Answer (score 3):

After doing some digging of my own thanks to this problem I found out that it is more than likely coming from the credential manager. 
I had no ssh keys since it was a fresh Gitlab account and it was not working with my username and password. The same setup however, was working on GitHub. After uninstalling git and reinstalling without the credential manager it worked.

Answer (score 3):

If it is on windows, go to Credential Manager, Windows Credentials and Delete the entries under Generic Credentials.

Try connecting again. This time, it should prompt you for the correct username and password.