# Can't clone gitlab repo via ssh on aws ec2

Tags: git, ssh, amazon-ec2, gitlab, git-clone

It seems that this problem is usual, but after a lot of searching, I didn't find any solutions.

I can't clone repositories on a gitlab instance hosted on aws ec2.

```
Clonage dans 'angular2'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried to use a config file for my ssh without result.

Here is the output of ssh -vT command

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [52.167.219.168] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/chd/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chd/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chd/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chd/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chd/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chd/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chd/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chd/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version  
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw
debug1: Host 'gitlab.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/chd/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/chd/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chd/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chd/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chd/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I precise I don't have the hand on aws instance.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm not using AWS, but I encountered a similar problem a few days ago. This answer to my question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43085700/2562819

Comment: Soory, I didn't tell I was on linux mint so I'm not concerned by Windows credential manger.

Comment: What about the 2nd bullet point from my link? Have you confirmed yet whether there's an SSH key saved to your account?

Comment: Well, yes, the key registerd in my account is the same as in my .ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: You are using private repo or public repo?

Comment: The repo is private, but I have the rights, no problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your private key is not accepted by the server:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/chd/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
```

Make sure the `/home/chd/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is in the gitlab.com SSH keys.

Comment: Yes, I entered the good public key (same in the file id_rsa.pub and in my gitlab account)

Answer (score -1):

change the remote url from ssh to https
use `git remote origin set-url <your https url>` to change in the directory where you initialized the git repo

Comment: Https is not supported by the Gitlab instance

Comment: It is in general. Are you using a self hosted version or something else?

Comment: Seems to be the way is configured the the gitlab instance. As I said, I don't have the hand on this.

Comment: ok,  do one thing - go to the amazon instance, and write `ssh-keygen`. and just press enter 2-3 times. you will get something like [this](http://corlan.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ssh-2.jpg)<br>
just copy the path from the terminal (just like in the screenshot) - /Users/...../.ssh/id_rsa.pub
now on your ssh instance type `cat <THE COPIED PATH>`<br>
copy the output<br>
go to gitlabs profile settings > add ssh keys > paste it , save it and it will work

Comment: I did it already. I tried many times. This doesn't work here and I don't know why. That's the point. I precise I have an another gitlab instance and I run connection via ssh without problems.

Comment: can you give the output of `git config --list` on your server

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access on the server. I mean, I'm not the owner of the repo but I have the access right. No problem with that. I'm in the same group as people who have no problem.

Comment: how are you trying to clone if you dont have access to the server?

Comment: I have the user rights for the gitlab instance, but no rights over the amazon server hosting gitlab.

Comment: no i am talking about the amazon ec2 server where you are cloning the code

Comment: Ok, I have no access. I just have the rights for using the graphical interface of gitlab. I have no other access. And my own shell...

Comment: git clone + I paste from gitlab ssh clipboard. Classical way.

Comment: on your system or a server?